# SciKit Learn when the data contains strings or boolean values

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have a dataframe that looks like this (it is obviously much bigger):

```
id     points isAvailable frequency   Score
abc1   325    True        93.0        0.01
def2   467    False       80.1        0.59
ghi3   122    True        90.3        1 
jkl4   546    True        84.0        0
mno5   355    False       93.5        0.99
```

I want to see how much the features `points`, `isAvailable` and `frequency` influence the `Score`. I want to use Random Forests:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams.update({'figure.figsize': (12.0, 8.0)})
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 14})

X = df
y = df['Score']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=12)
rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I get the following error: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'abc1'`

Questions:

1. How can I pre-process the data? What happens to the boolean variables?
2. Is it wrong to even include the `id` column in X?

I was thinking of using something like `df = df.astype({"a": int, "b": complex})` but I don't really know how in this case and I read that there are special algorithms for encoding.

Comment: This [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/inspection/plot_permutation_importance.html) would be helpful but since you are aiming to feature importance and its effect on `score`  you can check this [source](https://mljar.com/blog/feature-importance-in-random-forest/).

Comment: @Mario thank you, that's exactly where I took it from, the mljar link. But now I realize I should have added an extra column to X, for these feature names, I think?

Comment: Right and using `SHAP` could fulfill your request. You can see how those columns/features contributed on output which is `score` in your case.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to remove the `score` column from the `X` dataset: it is the label of you data, so it should not be used as a feature.

Second, assuming that the `id` column is an identifier for you data, you should remove it from `X`. It is like if you were trying to analyze a dataset of weight of a group of persons: you would remove their names because there is no correlation between their names and their weight.

Last, to deal with the boolean variables, there are some encoding methods, like you said (for example [this one](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)), but since the value can be only `0` or `1`, it should be fine if you convert `False = 0`, `True = 1`
You can do it with this code (assuming `df` is the name of you DataFrame):

```
df['isAvailable'] = (df['isAvailable'] == True).astype(int)
```

Comment: I don't think `score` means label. It could be used for labeling.

Comment: @Mario score is something that I computed/assumed and I want to see how much it is influenced by all these features.